# yii2 doesn't work $this->redirect

Tags: javascript, php, web, yii2

I'm new in yii2. When i click button, jquery triggers event that send ajax request to controller. Here's code:

```
$("#save").on('click', function() {
        var data = 'test';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?r=site%2Fcreate-mockup',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {dat: data},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

In controller creats instance of Mockup class

```
 public function actionCreateMockup()
    {
      if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
      {
          $create_model = new Mockup();
          //filling $create_model
          return $this->redirect(Url::to(['site/saved-mockups']));
       }
     }
```

when i delete $create_model = new Mockup(); //filling $create_model, then it's work.
Mockup.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Mockup extends ActiveRecord
{

}

?>
```

Comment: And what does it have in common with Laravel? I've removed Laravel tag

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ajax to submit your form and expecting a response back in your ajax `success` callback you could just continue using JavaScript to handle the rest of the scenarios and redirect the user once the data submitted is saved.

here is something to get you going

```
$("#save").on('click', function() {
    var data = 'test';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=site%2Fcreate-mockup',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {dat: data},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.success){
                  window.location = response.route //redirect on success
            }else{
                 //handle errors here
            }
        }
    });
});
```

than in your controller

```
    public function actionCreateMockup()
    {
      if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
      {
          $create_model = new Mockup();
          //filling $create_model
          \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
          if($create_model->load(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $create_model->save()){
             return [
                'success'=> true,
                'route'=> Url::to(['site/saved-mockups'])
             ];
           }else{
             return [
                'success'=> false,
                'errors'=> $create_model->getErrros();
            ];
        }
       }
     }
```